# Adding string to a List using await in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, startup

I am trying to get Active Directory userid asynchronously in `startup.cs` file. At the end list return null value.

- ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application
- Visual Studio 2019

This is the code I have

```
string mylanid = "";         

app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    if ((RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)))
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "sh";
        psi.Arguments = "-c whoami";
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = psi
        };

        proc.Start();

        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        proc.WaitForExit();

        mylanid = output;                   
    }
    else
    {
        mylanid = Environment.UserName;
    }

    List<returnedId> listData = new List<returnedId>();
    returnedId retrnTbl = new returnedId();
    retrnTbl.userRole = mylanid;
    listData.Add(retrnTbl);
});
```

Instead of list if I use below code. It reflects the correct result but I want that string value to be stored in `List`.

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync(mylanId);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify more about the scenario and requirement that requires getting information for the user who is currently logged on to the server system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by doing below steps;

Firs I added this line of code at the top of `Startup.cs`

```
public List<string> listData = new List<string>();
```

Second , in `in ConfigurationServices` I added this code;

```
services.AddSingleton<List<string>>(listData.ToList());
```

And Third step , I added `string` data to `List<string>` ;

```
  listData.Add(mylanid);
```

And it worked . Thanks